# Why is my webview app downloading .bin files?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

So I built this application for webmail but when I want to download attachments(files in mail)
nothing happens. Today I inserted this code in MainActivity.java:

```
myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

            DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            myManager.enqueue(myRequest);
        }
    });
```

After that my files are being downloaded in .bin extension and there is no original file name. I added these permissions in android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
```

And here is full code of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://webmail.carnet.hr/login.php");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

            DownloadManager.Request myRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            myRequest.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            myRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            DownloadManager myManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            myManager.enqueue(myRequest);
        }
    });










}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

I really want to finish this app so if you have any sugestions or want to help please do!

Comment: If you are sending email attachments from Outlook, it has a nasty habit of sending a winmail.dat attachment. This is due to some RTF styling. Google it around. You may have to learn how to read that attachment.

Comment: Can I do anything with mimetype? And has that command any connection with my problem?